# Searching with search options doesn't return questions newer than March 21, 2018 ~11AM

Tags: bug, search

**UPDATE (1:45 PM):** Seems like it's working now.

---

When [searching for something with a search option enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20closed%3Ano), the results don't contain questions that are newer than March 21, 2018 ~11AM UTC:

[image: screenshot of search with search options]

This does not occur when [there are no search options in the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript):

[image: screenshot of search without search options]

The results also have frozen vote/answer counts:

[image: search with search options, question with 0 indicated votes]
[image: meanwhile, the question has 1 upvote]

I emptied my cache, but nothing changed.

It only occurs on Stack Overflow AFAIK (I tested it on Meta SO and Super User as well).

What happened here?

Comment: It's working now. Any information about what happened?

Comment: _"I emptied my cache, but nothing changed."_ did You tried other browser as well?